# Handling missing animation transition

Tags: unity, animation-states

My problem is in the animator, when an animation parameter is triggered, there are some unexpected cases that there is no animation transition from the current state to the state I want to go to, since I forgot to add in the transitions.

The solution I can think of now is to handle such cases, if they happen, then transition to that state I want to go to from "any state" instead. Do you guys think it's a good approach? or any better ideas?

Comment: Can you give us an example of such a transition that you would not simply add to your graph as an explicit link?

Comment: The solution is to carefully go through the controller and add any transitions that you forgot, not to add transitions from Any State as a workaround.